# CPF not adding initial state to newly inserted documents in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

We have a number of `CPF`s configured in our DB. Most of them are configured with collection scopes.We are noticing for some time that documents inserted into those collections, are not set with any `cpf:state` or `cpf:last-updated`.
Only `cpf:processing-status` and `cpf:property-hash` are set on them. My understanding is, once `cpf:processing-status` is set, post-commit triggers would set `cpf:state` to `http://marklogic.com/states/initial` for newly inserted documents. But that's not happening,and therefore unprocessed documents are piling up. What could be some possible reasons for this? What are some ways to investigate what's going on?

Version 7.0.5

Comment: From a recent email chain, Mary H from MarkLogic explained how to enable the CPF trace events for troubleshooting. It may help.

"Enable the CPF trace events:

Go to the Diagnostics tab under Groups/Default. Enable trace events, and type CPF into the box. Then try again. You should see some trace in the log about what CPF sees and what it is doing."

Comment: @david-ennis That is worth a (partial) answer..

Comment: @grtjn.  Yeah - it specifically answers the second question. but since it was not the leading question, so I decided for now to keep the answer question clean for now.

Comment: Thanks @david-ennis . Will do and ask follow-up questions if needed.

Comment: @DavidEnnis  Hope it's not too late to revive this thread. On checking the CPF trace events we found out the cpf:state could not be set because ETC getting full.It seemed rather odd considering how little ETC should be required to update the properties fragment of a document.Granted that other transactions might be using up the ETC,but should there not be a fail-safe mechanism for that ,or should the exception not be put in the properties fragment?

Comment: HI.  If the expanded tree cache is getting full, then some loop, some xPath Expression, something is probably not running in an efficient way somewhere and should probably be  reviewed.

As far as if CPF should do more - well, in your xQuery that is run, you can also add try/catch statements/etc and catch the errors yourself and react/log appropriately.. ML it does let you know what is happening by way of a trace event. ~~~~~~~~ Note: My response if limited in that (1) I do not know your code and (2) I don't know all the details of CPF as I usually use triggers directly to keep overhead down.